# Apply a transition effect when loading next page through UI Router

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, angular-ui-router, router

In this below example

http://plnkr.co/edit/IzimSVsstarlFviAm7S7?p=preview

```
<div class="container">
<div ui-view></div>
```

when i am clicking on home or about button the view part is loading directly. But i need to move the  current page(home) from right to left and new page(about) should load from right to left(transition effect)

How can this possible?

Comment: well you could try css3 animation so the body of the about page gets moved in from the right and the home moves out left or you could use ng-animate

Comment: body of home and about both are same

Comment: well then just have 2 different divs around the content of each page and apply the css transition to those divs url change or button click

Comment: yes, i can place two divs and  as you said i can do the css transition. But the problem, when i am clicking the home/about buttons both divs are loading  with contents in same time and then the transition happening. I dont want to load the data in to current displaying page.Want to load data in second div then transition should happen. If i have only two buttons then i can manage with two view names. But i have more than two buttons.

Comment: well if you are loading both on pageload, then you need to do this with javascript angular i am afraid or you could try to set ng-class and set the transition when home is clicked or when about is clicked smth like that

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by using ng-animate, added below css in to my code

```
[data-ui-view].ng-enter, [data-ui-view].ng-leave {
              position: absolute;
              left: 0;
              right: 0;
              -webkit-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
                -moz-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
                -o-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
                transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
            }

            [data-ui-view].ng-enter {
              opacity: 0;
             -webkit-transform:translate(960px);
              -moz-transform:translate(960px);
              transform:translate(960px);

            }

            [data-ui-view].ng-enter-active {
              opacity: 1;
             -webkit-transform:translate(0px);
              -moz-transform:translate(0px);
              transform:translate(0px);
            }

            [data-ui-view].ng-leave {
              opacity: 1;
              /*padding-left: 0px;*/  
               -webkit-transform:translate(0px);
              -moz-transform:translate(0px);
              transform:translate(0px);

            }

            [data-ui-view].ng-leave-active {
              opacity: 0;
              /*padding-left: 100px;*/
              -webkit-transform:translate(-960px);
              -moz-transform:translate(-960px);
              transform:translate(-960px);
            }
```